# Django filter a ForeignKey field when it is null

Tags: django, foreign-keys, nullable

Let's say I have two tables in Django, `TableA` and `TableB`. Table A contains some boolean field, `bool`, and `TableB` contains a foreign key field, `for_field` to `TableA`, which can be Null.

```
class TableA(models.Model):
    bool = models.BooleanField()

class TableB(models.Model):
    for_field = models.ForeignKey('TableA', null=True)
```

If I want to filter TableB so as to get all the entries where `for_field.bool` is `True` or `for_field` is `Null`, what is the shortest way to achieve this?

I'm using `.filter((Q(for_field__is_null=True) | Q(for_field__bool=True))`, but I wonder if there's shorter code for this.

Comment: Have you tried `.exclude(for_field__bool=False)`? Is this giving same results?

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not sure whether django will raise an error if trying to access `bool` in a `Null` foreign key field.

Comment: A minor improvement: `Q(for_field__is_null=True)` is equivalent to `Q(for_field=None)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some experiments it seems that `.exclude(for_field__bool=False)` will contain also `for_field__isnull=True` entries and will not raise any exceptions. You can be sure by executing `.exclude(for_field__bool=False).filter(for_field__isnull=True)` and see some results also.

And honestly I don't know which option is faster, but IMO your variant with two `Q` objects much more readable because it shows logic you're really want. So I actually suggest you to stick with it.

Comment: Thanks! This will probably do. I agree that showing the underlying logic makes the code more readable in most cases, but in this case I have many similar `for_field`s I need to concatenate in the filter query, so it would produce a really long and ugly line of code.

Comment: The `exclude` version is nice if you have many fields, because you can chain them. `exclude(some_field=False).exclude(some_other_field=False)` etc.

Comment: **FieldError at /.../
Unsupported lookup 'bool' for BooleanField or join on the field not permitted.** when using bool on a foreign key filtering.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure, that your option is the shortest possible (correct me if I'm wrong). That is because you can't do OR queries without Q objects.